# Sending email via Axapta

Tags: axapta

I've managed to get my Axapta 3.0 to send email via the printjobSettings class. However, there doesn't appear to be anywhere I can create a body for my email. Currently I can send email with an attachment but I'd like to include some text to provide some context for the attachment for the recipient.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

The class printJobSettings has a method mailSubject for setting the subject of the email that gets generated, but there is no method for setting the body of the message.  printJobSettings is a kernel class, so you can't modify it.

To actually send the email, the kernel passes a printJobSettings object to the method Info.ReportSendMail, which you can modify. So as a work around, pack your subject and body together in the subject, then unpack them in ReportSendMail.

In your report:

```
printJobSettings.mailSubject(msgSubject + '|' + msgBody);
```

In Info.ReportSendMail:

```
subjectAndBody=printJobSettings.mailSubject();
delimiterPos=strFind(subjectAndBody,'|',1,strlen(subjectAndBody));
if(delimiterPos>0)
{
    msgSubject=subStr(subjectAndBody,1,delimiterPos-1);
    msgBody=subStr(subjectAndBody,delimiterPos+1,strlen(subjectAndBody)-delimiterPos);
}
else
{
    msgSubject=subjectAndBody;
    msgBody='Axapta Report';
}
```